# OnTouchListener activity intent wallpaper service

Tags: android

My activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
}

public void openService(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
    intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, mWallpaperService.class));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

mWallpaperService

```
public class mWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new mEngine();
}

private class mEngine extends Engine {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I get events in onTouchEvent here is it's description

```
     /**
     * Called as the user performs touch-screen interaction with the
     * window that is currently showing this wallpaper.  Note that the
     * events you receive here are driven by the actual application the
     * user is interacting with, so if it is slow you will get fewer
     * move events.
     */
     public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
     }
```

I think I'm loosing some touch events, my **question** is how do I add raw  OnTouchListener?

I've tried to add `implements View.OnTouchListener` to all classes, but no luck, I don't have a view to register a new listener.